# Slow loading speed when using window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this script to hide the `div` with the id `#main-slider`.

But every time I load my page I can see the div for like 1 or 2 seconds and then it disappears, is there any way to make it take effect sooner?

Thank you.

```
window.onload = function() {
    if($(window).width() > 991) 
    {
        $('#main-slider').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#main-slider').addClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the `DOMContentLoaded` event

Answer (score 1):

`window.onload` waits for every element to be loaded correctly. You can either use `document.onload` or you can use the event `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `css @media` for that. Try that:

```
@media (min-width: 991px) {
  #my-element {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: on my case it's gonna be max-width: 991px, it works too, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use **document.onload** instead, it's fired earlier. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/4108884

Comment: Yeap, [Here is an example](http://web.archive.org/web/20150405114023/http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add the class 'hidden' to the 'main-slider' html element in the html page. 
So the class get added at first, so that the main-slider element is hidden and then according to the condition it gets visible or not. Now with your check, it should work